# Export an animation as .avi file with sound?

Tags: export, sound, video

If I have a list `myTb` containing `Image` objects, I can export the list as an .avi file using the command

```
Export["myavi01.avi", myTb, "FrameRate" -> 30]
```

However, what if I want to create an .avi file with sound? The documentation does not mention the proper syntax that has to be used to add a `Sound` object while exporting an .avi file. Is it possible? What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible at the moment, although I'd love to be corrected on this one.

As it happens, essentially the same question has been asked before on the Wolfram Community ([Can I create a movie including synchronized sound?](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/190809)), as a followup to a question asked in the comments section of an older *Mathematica* Q&A: [Creating Movie Files](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/15/mathematica-qa-creating-movie-files/).

Unfortunately, the consensus seems to be that using a dedicated movie editor to add a synchronized soundtrack to your *Mathematica*-generated silent movies is still the only viable approach.